# Foreach Loop Only Iterating Once - PHP

Tags: php, foreach, copy, domdocument, explode

I was looking for a PHP script to grab images from a few websites, but I couldn't find one that was universal and allowed scraping of multiple pages.. so I built one.

It asks for a save-to path and a list of web-pages to scrape images from, delimited by a comma. The script explodes the user inputted web pages by comma and then loops through each one. It will always scrape the first web page fine but then it skips the rest.

Here is the entire script. Feel free to copy it to localhost and run it, you'll see what I mean.

```
<?php
error_reporting( 0 );

if(isset($_POST['doit'])){
    $scrapethese = explode(",",$_POST['website']);
    foreach($scrapethese as $scrapethis){
        $cleanit = str_replace(" ", "", $scrapethis);
        $html = file_get_contents($cleanit);
        $dom = new domDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            $fullimgpath = $img->getAttribute('src');
            $slashexp = explode('/', $fullimgpath);
            $lastindex = count($slashexp)-1;
            $shortpath = $slashexp[$lastindex];
            $filename = $_POST['folder']."\\".$shortpath;
            if(copy($fullimgpath, $filename)){
                echo $slashexp[$lastindex]." Saved<br />";
            }else{
                echo "<b style='color:red;'>Could not save img: </b>".$filename."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}else{
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="doit" value="x" />
    <label>The complete path to the page you'd like to scrape. You may enter multiple paths seperated by commas.</label><br />
    <textarea name="website" /></textarea><br />
    <label>Path to the folder you want to save images to</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="folder" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="save all images" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

If anyone can provide some insight as to why the script is not looping through all websites when multiple are provided I would really appreciate it.

Comment: var_dump($imgs); see if it is actually returning an array/object from $dom->getElementsByTagName() or if its just returning a single or a string.  You may have to do some pre-exploding to get imgs as an array/object you can for each through.

Comment: When i vardump it I get `object(DOMNodeList)[2]` ..but I got it once, where as var_dump should have printed twice as there were 2 webpages, therefore the loop should have iterated twice.

Comment: so its your  primary loop thats failing then not the img get loop is $scrapethese actually an array ?

Comment: Correct, `foreach($scrapethese as $scrapethis)` is the part that's giving me trouble

Comment: so var_dump($scrapethese); is it returning an array? or just a string or what ?  What was your input string for $_POST['website'];?  For your input your using a text area are you entering the websites on different lines in which case you'll need to remove the line breaks \n before you then explode on the comma's etc.  Bit of input validation may fix your problem.  Also the explode will fail if only a single site it put in so again you'll need to validate first

Comment: I actually haven't tried it with a single site. Yes, `$scrapethese` is an array and no, I'm not using linebreaks. The input looks like this: `http://www.website1.com/gallery.php, http://www.website2.com/gallery.php`

Comment: Could it have something to do with the way I'm assigning `$dom`? Are you allowed to create/reassign a variable/object in a loop like that? I don't do much OOP.

Comment: It should be fine you could try destroying the object but don't think that'd help as that would only effect your inner loop not your external loop and you should see some warning in logs for failure.  Try doing just this `$count=0;$scrapethese = explode(",",$_POST['website']);foreach($scrapethese as $scrapethis){ echo $count;$count++; }`  See if its at least counting your input array correctly if it is then there's deffo an error in the inner loop but I assume you have warnings etc turned on for coding so you should see the error

Comment: Errors/warnings are turned off because I was getting DOM errors from the websites I had no control over. I did what you posted and got `01` as the output, which is correct as I entered 2 websites. I don't see how there could be anything wrong with my inner loop as it loops thru all images on the first page just fine.

Comment: I also tried using `unset($dom)` but no effect

Comment: @Adelphia You need to remove the `error_reporting(0)` call (and preferably replace it with `error_reporting(-1)` while debugging). You can suppress the document loading errors with the `@` operator on the `$dom->loadHTML($html);` line - one of the few places where its use is acceptable. You can also do it by controlling the error reporting method in libxml itself. Can you show the actual URLs you are passing in when you test please?

Comment: Also you should consider using a newline as a separator in the textarea instead of a comma. A comma can legally appear unencoded in a URL, but a newline can't.

Comment: [This](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZIOqhe) works fine.

Comment: @DaveRandom Turning error reporting back on is ultimately what helped me realize that the max execution time was set too low. I got it going now. If you'd like to post what you said as an answer I'll give it to you.